# Detecting SURF features - disappointed by the performance

Tags: performance, opencv, parameters, surf

I was looking to extract SURF features (or something similar) in an application that gets new images at 25 FPS. I thought feature extracting would be possible at least close to real time. I tried OpenSURF with the same parameters that are supplied by the demo file, and was quite devastated to see that at a resolution of 640x480 my 2 GHz Core2 Duo takes 5 to 8 seconds for a single image.

1) Is that normal?

2) Can I adjust parameters to get worse results but faster execution time?

3) I actually do not require scale / rotation invariance, just good features to track between frames (the camera is in a fixed position) / between different lighting conditions. Is there a viable alternative that might run (near) real time?

Comment: Decrease spatial resolution to improve temporal resolution? I've no idea of the algorithmic complexity, is SURF not living up to its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes it is normal SURF is poor on performance :(

2) You should use other descriptor and detector, as I tested the Orb is one of the best and fastest, but in my opinion if You want to have the fastets result use FAST and BRIEF it does not have rotation invariance but it is extremly fast in compare with SURF :)

try this I hope you will be sattisfied and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723435/is-the-good-features-to-track-theory-some-way-implemented-in-opencv)

Comment: Wow, Orb is indeed very fast, and VERY usable for our application. Got great results with it. If I could up vote you I would :-)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is an issue you might want to try the GPU version of SURF implemented in OpenCV's GPU module:

```
OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/gpu/src/surf.cpp
```

Comment: @Laurel, how big an improvement did you see with GPU SURF vs CPU?

Answer (score 1):

The one of the problems of the SURF in openCV is very big amount of the type conversions (double<->float, float->int) and it takes a time because of frequently calling of these basic functions. You can try to look into the source code and to try to modify it to get better performance.

Comment: that's right, as explained here, I wonder why developers don't fix it: http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/06/a-few-thoughts-about-cvround/

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `hessianThreshold` parameter. The greater it is, the lesser features will be found, and less time will be spent on detecting them.

In my case with [default value](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/df7/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1SURF.html) of 100 it took ~10sec to get all the matches. Increasing the value to 1000 reduced time to 1-2sec without hurting the final result.

For more details see [Introduction to SURF (Speeded-Up Robust Features)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/df/dd2/tutorial_py_surf_intro.html).