# Is the "Good Features to Track" theory some way implemented in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I have read in : [this PDF](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/jchai/CPSC641/shi_tomasi_94.pdf) that If I want to track object I do not have to track all the images(BRUTEFORCE) in video stream. It is enough to get the object in image of the video sequence and on the other images just focus on that object, It is some way implemented in OpenCV?

PS.: I know it is pretty old text :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

As documented [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html),
the `cv::goodFeaturesToTrack` function finds the most prominent corners in the image or in the specified image region, as described in Shi94 (the paper you linked):

Comment: So It gives me back the right corners, but in the pdf, it is said that it is way to track only that object, so I have understood that I do not have to search for the object in whole image. I just need to to have thes features and track there move(transition, scaling or rotation) it is too implemented ? But your answer is good :)

Comment: OpenCV only implements the 'Good Features To Track' algorithm to determine robust features in an image. The paper is only concerned with finding good image features to track, not good objects to track. It does not know what the object you are trying to track is (ie. a vase), just that certain parts of each picture (corners etc.) will be able to be found reliably in subsequent pictures of the same scene. Using those features, however, you should be able to then calculate descriptors (SURF/SIFT) of the region around each good feature and perhaps match them to find your object.

Comment: I quote: "In this paper we show how to monitor the quality of image features during TRACKING by using a measure of feature between the FIRST AND THE CURRENT FRAME....."<--because of that I write you the previous comment, but you are right I accepted your answer thanks PS.: i prefer using ORB it is faster :P